# Traduccion consulta eloquen

Tags: laravel-5

Alguno sabe como puedo traducir esta consulta en eloquen?

update usuarios set asignacion='gestion' where usuario_ad='danielad';

Tengo tres filas que pertenecen al usuario danielad, por lo tanto quiero en otro de  sus campos el cual se llama asignacion quede con el nombre gestion.

Comment: Hasta hora lo unico que logro es que me borre el primero, pero yo quiero los tres registros.  https://paste.laravel.io/57f48469-28ad-41fe-af79-11b9e2023618

Answer (score 0):

primero el uso de la función de find() solo busca el primer valor, está diseñado para limitar una sola consulta.

la función de find esta diseñado para consulta el id que corresponde la llave primaria que desea busca

por el cual se deber realizar una consulta en la tabla de usuario donde me busque el nombre de daniela y  utilizar un foreach

```
public function asignar(Request $request) 
{
$valor = $request->valor;//donde obtiene el dato "daniela"
$consulta=usuarios::where('name',$valor)->get();

foreach ($consulta as $value) {

  $userad = usuarios::findOrFail($value->id);//limite de un registro
  $userad->asignacion = $user->usuario_ad;
  $userad->save();
}

return redirect()->route('cuenta.tareas')->with('success','Registro actualizado satisfactoriamente');

}
```

Comment: Gracias marcos, he realizado tus cambios, y modifique los campos por los de mi bd... pero sigo actualizando el primer registro.. no quiere actualizar los otros, a pesar de que la regla esta ahi.            https://paste.laravel.io/b24a3e57-6863-411f-86af-a03fd3a4a659

Comment: por que en este caso el where no tiene un igual =?   $consulta=usuarios::where('id',$valor)->get();